# SUPEE 6788 - What do I need to do with overrides

Tags: magento-1.9, template, security, patches, supee-6788

Looking at the actually .sh patch I can see it updates files such as

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
```

I have my overridden the .phtml with my own in my theme I would need to apply the same changes the releveant files?

```
/app/design/frontend/rwd/[my theme name here]/template/customer/form/register.phtml
```

Obviously this is just an example of 1 file that the patch changes so if I do need to update them too, I presume I would need to review what files have been changed and update accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check **which changes have been made** in these files which you modified in your own template and transfer/copy then to your files.

A `git diff` or having a look at the patch file will help you with this.

In the specific case mentioned above the `git diff` will show you that a hidden form_key input was added:

```
diff --git a/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml b/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
index ca7ac92..2f37165 100644
--- a/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
+++ b/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
@@ -43,6 +43,7 @@
         <div class="fieldset">
             <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl() ?>" />
             <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />
+            <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
             <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Personal Information') ?></h2>
             <ul class="form-list">
                 <li class="fields">
```

You need to copy this line into your template in `/app/design/frontend/rwd/[my theme name here]/template/customer/form/register.phtml`.